# First assembly program: working with strings and integers

Tags: performance, beginner, assembly, x86

I started learning assembly some days ago and I wrote my first program today. Nothing exceptional here: some user inputs, strings manipulations, integer to string conversion etc... The only purpose was to test some things. I would like to have your reviews and advices to improve my code. Also if i didn't make big mistakes.

I'm looking for advice about instructions alignment in loops for example. Except inserting nops, I don't have other idea. Or know the size of all instructions and predict the good alignment on 16 or 32 bytes boundaries.

```
SYS_READ    equ 3
SYS_WRITE   equ 4
SYS_EXIT    equ 1
STDIN       equ 0
STDOUT      equ 1

%macro printm 2
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, %1
    mov edx, %2
    int 0x80
%endmacro

%macro readm 2
    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, %1
    mov edx, %2
    int 0x80
%endmacro

%macro prolog 0
    push ebp,
    mov ebp, esp
%endmacro

%macro epilog 0    
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
%endmacro

%use smartalign

section .text

global _start

_start:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    and esp, 0xFFFFFFF0
    
    ; first check if our strlen proc works
    push dword msgbegin
    call strlen
    add esp, byte 4
    cmp eax, lenbegin
    jne .exit       ; it works, we continue
    
    ; after we copy the msgbegin in string strdst
    mov ecx, lenbegin
    mov esi, msgbegin
    mov edi, strdst
    rep movsb

    ; we print the string to check if the memcpy is good 
    printm strdst, lenbegin

    ; after we ask for user to enter two number (1 digit each)
    printm msgbinp1, leninp1

    readm num1, 2

    printm msgbinp2, leninp2

    readm num2, 2

    ; user input to enter a number greater than one digit
    printm msgbinp3, leninp3

    readm bignum, 4

    ; we convert this string number to an (dword) integer value
    mov edx, bignum
    call atoi
    ; we compare it with 123 to check if atoi worked
    cmp eax, dword 123
    jne .exit     ; exit if bignum != 123

    ; need to strip line feed from bignum
    printm bignum, 4
    printm msgoutp, lenoutp

    ; now we compute the sum with the first two digits
    mov al, byte [num1]
    sub al, '0'
    mov bl, byte [num2]
    sub bl, '0'
    add al, bl
    add al, '0'

    mov [sum], al
    
    ; we put the string msgres to uppercase
    mov esi, msgres

.next_char:
    lodsb
    test al, al     ; check for end of string
    jz .done      
    cmp al, 'a'     ; ignore unless in range
    jl .next_char
    cmp al, 'z'
    jg .next_char
    sub al, 0x20 ; convert to upper case         
    mov [esi-1], al ; write back to string
    jmp .next_char

.done:

    printm msgres, lenres
    ; we print the sum
    printm sum, 1

.exit:    
    ; exiting the programm
    mov     eax, SYS_EXIT
    int     0x80

strlen:
    push edi
    mov edi, [esp + 8]
    sub ecx, ecx
    sub al, al
    mov ecx, -1
    cld
    repne scasb
    not ecx
    mov eax, ecx ; keep null term in size
    pop edi
    ret

atoi:
    xor eax, eax            ; zero a "result so far"
.top:
    movzx ecx, byte [edx]   ; get a character
    inc edx                 ; ready for next one
    cmp ecx, '0'            ; valid?
    jb .done
    cmp ecx, '9'
    ja .done
    sub ecx, '0'            ; "convert" character to number
    imul eax, 10            ; multiply "result so far" by ten
    add eax, ecx            ; add in current digit
    jmp .top                ; until done

.done:
    ret

    ; not implemented yet
rand:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    rdtsc

    xor edx, edx        ; to always fit

    div dword [ebp + 8] ; range
    mov eax, edx

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret    

section .data

    msgbegin db  "hello everyone !", 0xa, 0
    lenbegin equ $ - msgbegin
    msgbinp1 db  "Enter a digit : ", 0xa, 0
    leninp1 equ $ - msgbinp1
    msgbinp2 db  "Enter second digit : ", 0xa, 0
    leninp2 equ $ - msgbinp2
    msgbinp3 db  "Enter third digit : ", 0xa, 0
    leninp3 equ $ - msgbinp3
    msgoutp db  "is equal to 123 !", 0xa, 0
    lenoutp equ $ - msgoutp
    msgres db  "sum of x and y is ", 0xa,  0
    lenres equ $ - msgres
    strdst times lenbegin db 0

segment .bss

    sum     resb 1
    num1    resb 2
    num2    resb 2
    bignum  resd 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I see that it prints messages like "_hello everyone !_", "_Enter a digit :_" and "_Enter second digit :_" but It would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about what the code achieves in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: I edited my code with more comments. It implements strlen, print, user input, a toupper sequence. I hope it would help. I would like to have reviews about : mistakes and major errors and code improvisation. For example, in my atoi function, I have to use imul for the conversion. I know that imul is really time consuming. Maybe it would be faster with bitshift instructions.

Comment: re: zeroing AL for `scasb`: [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33666617) - use `xor eax,eax`. Also, `repne scasb` is fairly low-performance; SSE2 can go *much* faster even for small strings, especially if your buffer is known to be aligned.  (Only rep movs / rep stos have "fast strings" microcode) re: atoi: some more optimization is possible with LEA, and to detect ASCII '0'..'9' inputs more efficiently as part of converting to integer 0..9: [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057)

Comment: Code alignment often isn't a huge deal these days, with CPUs running from a uop cache.  The JCC erratum performance pothole for Skylake CPUs is a bigger deal for code alignment: [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646).  Usually just assemble and look at the output to see if there's anything problematic, and/or use `perf stat -all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,idq.mite_uops` or similar to look for high counts of legacy decode (MITE uops)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do better with aligning the text. You got comments that start all over the place and instead of separating the instruction from its operands with a single space character, you could adopt the more 'assembly way of doing things' and align the operands (and anything else) tabularly. See my snippets below.

The mention `%use smartalign` only enables the feature of the multibyte `nop`'s. You still have to use the normal `align 16` macro to get the desired padding.

You have included a `cld` instruction in the *strlen* subroutine. Normally you can trust the direction flag to be clear (unless of course you yourself toggled it for some reason) and only issue a single `cld` when your program begins.

Although the *byte* tag in `add esp, byte 4` is fine in order to avoid the longer dword form that NASM would generate without optimizations, I see no reason to write `cmp eax, dword 123` as the dword form would be the default here.
I find NASM is confusing in how it treats these immediate operands, so do yourself a favor and don't write these size tags but always assemble with the `-O2` option.

For your *strlen* you used a parameter on the stack and for your *atoi* you used a parameter in a register. Both methods are fine and especially in the context of exploring the assembly language. However for a more serious program I would be inclined to say that the author should make their mind up.

> ```
> sum     resb 1
> num1    resb 2
> num2    resb 2
> bignum  resd 1
> ```

Data alignment is important. Since the .bss section is dword-aligned by default, you should have put the dword-sized *bignum* on top. At least that was what I first read. As it turns out, *bignum* is not meant to be a dword at all! It is a string that happens to hold 4 bytes. You should write this as `bignum resb 4`. (It can stay put).

> ```
> cmp eax, lenbegin
> jne .exit
> mov ecx, lenbegin
> ```

This is a missed opportunity to write the shortest code. If the branch wasn't taken you know that EAX is equal to *lenbegin*. Then best setup ECX from EAX (`mov ecx, eax`). It will shave off 3 bytes.

### About *strlen*

The preferred way to zero a register is through `xor`ing the register with itself.
If you are going to load the ECX register whole with `mov ecx, -1`, then it's useless to also zero ECX beforehand.
Because you chose to use `repne scasb` and apparently want to follow some register convention, you had to push EDI and allow ECX to get clobbered.
Below is my version of this code using a simple loop and nothing more than the EAX register:

```
; IN (stack) OUT (eax)
strlen:
    mov   eax, [esp+4]               ; Address of string
.a: cmp   byte [eax], 0
    lea   eax, [eax+1]               ; EAX++ without disturbing flags
    jne   .a
    sub   eax, [esp+4]               ; Length is 'zero-terminator-included'
    ret
```

### About *atoi*

You can condense the part that checks the validity of the character and that converts the character to number, to just 3 instructions: `sub ecx, '0'` `cmp cl, 9` `ja .done`.
You can speedup the part that multiplies the current result and that adds the newest digit with a couple of `lea` instructions: `lea eax, [eax + eax * 4]` `lea eax, [ecx + eax * 2]`.
You can avoid the unconditional branch `jmp .top` simply by re-arranging the code. Having jumps that execute repeatedly is costly.

```
; IN (edx) OUT (eax) MOD (ecx,edx)
atoi:
    xor   eax, eax                  ; Result = 0
    jmp   .b
.a: lea   eax, [eax + eax * 4]      ; Result * 10 + Digit
    lea   eax, [ecx + eax * 2]
.b: movzx ecx, byte [edx]           ; Fetch character
    inc   edx
    sub   ecx, '0'                  ; Convert ["0","9"] to [0,9]
    cmp   cl, 10
    jb    .a
    ret
```

### About *ucase*

You have inlined the uppercase conversion. This actively harms the readability of your program. And anyway, it's a conversion that deserves its own subroutine.
The ASCII codes are unsigned quantities. It's best to use the unsigned conditional branches on them, so `jb` and `ja`.
Just like was the case with *atoi*, you can avoid the unconditional branch `jmp .next_char` by re-arranging the code.

```
; IN (esi) OUT () MOD (eax)
ucase:
    push  esi
    lodsb
    test  al, al                    ; Check end-of-string
    jz    .c      
.a: cmp   al, 'a'                   ; Ignore if not in ["a","z"]
    jb    .b
    cmp   al, 'z'
    ja    .b
    sub   al, 32                    ; Convert to upper case         
    mov   [esi-1], al               ; Update string
.b: lodsb
    test  al, al                    ; Check end-of-string
    jnz   .a
.c: pop   esi
    ret
```

### About code alignment

Consider the example of the *strlen* subroutine. It's not really the *strlen* label itself that you would want to align but rather the *.a* label inside because it gets repeatedly jumped to.

**Method 1 - on the execution path**

```
; IN (stack) OUT (eax)
strlen:
    mov   eax, [esp+4]               ; Address of string
    ALIGN 16                         ; (*)
.a: cmp   byte [eax], 0
    lea   eax, [eax+1]               ; EAX++ without disturbing flags
    jne   .a
    sub   eax, [esp+4]               ; Length is 'zero-terminator-included'
    ret
```

(*) Because 'smartalign' was enabled, NASM will pad with some multibyte nop instruction. This `nop` gets executed, and under circumstances it could even be another `jmp`. Read about this in the NASM manual chapter 5 paragraph 2.

**Method 2 - outside the execution path**

```
    times (15-($-$$+4+15) % 16) db 0 ; (**)
; IN (stack) OUT (eax)
strlen:
    mov   eax, [esp+4]               ; Address of string
.a: cmp   byte [eax], 0
    lea   eax, [eax+1]               ; EAX++ without disturbing flags
    jne   .a
    sub   eax, [esp+4]               ; Length is 'zero-terminator-included'
    ret
```

(**) This `times` prefix inserts just the right amount of padding bytes to have the local *.a* label paragraph-aligned. The number **4** in the expression is the length of the instruction `mov eax, [esp+4]`. In this case there's nothing additional that gets executed.

Comment: *only issue a single cld when your program begins.* - the i386 System V ABI guarantees that `cld` is clear on function call/return (thus at the top of `main`), and in the initial process environment (thus at the top of `_start`).  So you never need `cld` in a Linux program unless your own code used `std` somewhere.